# How to call a method from one window to another without creating an Instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, instance

On my Window, I click a button which then displays a pop-up window in front of my current window.

```
private void btnStandards_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StandardChooseScreen ChooseScreen = new StandardChooseScreen();
    ChooseScreen.Show();     
}
```

On the pop-up window, the user must tick a checkbox and press the 'Next' button.

```
private void btnStandardOption_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (chkNewStandard.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CreateNewStandard = true;
        StandardRedirect(CreateNewStandard, EditExistsingStandard, DeleteAStandard);
        this.Close();
    }
```

As you can see from the button click, I am calling `StandardDirect` which is a method from my previous Window, yet the method needs an instance and I do not want to create a new one, **is there a way to get the instance of the already opened Window in the background?**

Comment: When you create the pop up window, pass the current window as a parameter so that you can call the standard direct on the parent window.

Comment: @Venki How do you pass the current window instance as a parameter?

Comment: You pass the "this" to the Popup window. That is  StandardChoosenScreen choosenScreen = new StandardChoosenScreen(this);The constructor of StandardChosenScreen should choose the parent form instance as its parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it through the constructor of your popup:

```
public class YourPopupWindow : Form {
     private YourMainWindow _mainWindow;

    public YourPopupWindow(YourMainWindow mainWindow) {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    private void btnStandardOption_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (chkNewStandard.IsChecked) {
            CreateNewStandard = true;
            _mainWindow.StandardRedirect(CreateNewStandard, EditExistsingStandard, DeleteAStandard);
            // ^^^^^^^ this
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Your other option is to use `ShowDialog`.. so that your popup is a true modal window.

```
if (yourPopupInstance.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    if (yourPopupInstance.chkNewStandard.IsChecked) {
        CreateNewStandard = true;
        StandardRedirect(CreateNewStandard, EditExistsingStandard, DeleteAStandard);
        // you're still in the main window here
        yourPopupInstance.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you pass a current instance of the MainWindow to the constructor of the pop-up Window in the first place? As to open the popup window, I create a new instance of it and show it. Therefore I would need to pass the current instance of the MainwWindow upon startup of the pop-up window.

Comment: @Ben You would do something like this: `var popup = new YourPopupWindow(this);`.. where `this` is the main window.. where you're creating the popup.